# Left Align UICollectionViewCells only works when cells are not correct height, and stops working when scrolled

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to left align the cells in a UICollectionView, and I have used a GitHub repo to try and obtain this, link here:
https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout

I set up the CollectionView and its cells like so:

```
lazy var filterCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .left, verticalAlignment: .center)
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.register(filterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "filterCellId")
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.isScrollEnabled = true
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    return cv
}()


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return genrArray.count
}

let genArray = ["Test123", "LongTextTest", "Short", "S", "#LongLongLongLong"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "filterCellId", for: indexPath) as! filterCell

    cell.genText.text = genArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.genText.sizeToFit()
    cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.genText.frame.width + 25, height: 24)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.text = genArray[indexPath.row]
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: label.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: 0)

    return CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 25, height: 18)
}
```

This did nothing to the cells, so I added these lines of code into ViewDidLoad():

```
    let layout = AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .left, verticalAlignment: .center)
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    self.filterCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

The line that actually made a change in the CollectionView was         `layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`. But this still did not achieve the desired effect. This squished my cells and made them have a height of much smaller than 18 (the size declared in `sizeForItem`. When loaded up, the collectionView looks like this:

[image: First Load of CollectionView]

But when I scroll through the collectionView, it reverts back to normal as if the left alignment layout is not even there. It then looks like this:

[image: CollectionView after scrolling through]

The cells are the correct shape in that image, but the alignment/layout/spacing is off.

What am I doing wrong?